# NextJS dynamic routes not working on my localhost

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

```js
src/app/user/[username].js
```

[username].js file:

```js
import { useRouter } from 'next/router'

export default function User() {
  const router = useRouter()
  return (
    <p>
      {router.query.username}
    </p>
  );
}
```

When I go to `localhost:3000/user/john`, the user/username URL returns 404 not found.

[image]

I followed the examples in the current documentation exactly, but I still got the 404 output.
https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/routing/dynamic-routes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [documentation](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/dynamic-routes) for the App router states that your page should be at `app/user/[username]/page.js` instead of `app/user/[username].js`

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to use Next.js Pages router's dynamic routes, but you are configured the project with App router. Make sure you are reading correct docs or installed right Next.js project structure.